# Fancybox-rails gem does not load assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fancybox

```
/assets/fancybox-40d79ef494fcf5ca4727cb13b9e69c33.png 404 (Not Found)
```

This is see when i go on my page. Images for fancybox-rails gem does not load - i talk about images like close button ,background and other fancybox-rails css images. What i can do? I had that same problem with all my css and i change

```
url('something.jpg')
```

to

```
image-url('something.jpg')
```

but here i havent got any css file for this fancybox-rails gem , everything is in jquery.fancybox.js

On localhost everything works only on production server does not

Answer (score 6):

In case you use rails 4, the official fancybox-rails gem is currently not fully compatible with rails 4. You can use the gem from greinacker instead.

In your Gemfile, use:

```
gem 'fancybox-rails', :github => 'greinacker/fancybox-rails', :branch => 'rails4'
```

See https://github.com/hecticjeff/fancybox-rails/pull/26 for more informations.

Comment: I wasted N hours debugging this. I wish I could give you more than one up votes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, I'm not well versed in fancy box but rather the assets pipeline.

Go to your vendor directory and search for the assets there. if they don't exist manually place them in there.

If everything seems correct in your assets directory then it sounds like you need to precompile your assets for production.

`bundle exec run rake assets:precompile`

Comment: every thing is working now but not for fancybox gem. I remove fancybox-rails gem because it takes css from gem directory, and install colorbox. Now everything is ok.